# Open source PHP framework

Tags: php

So I have started a PHP framework called ExCx and I haven't really had much experience in the professional development business.

I was just wondering if my structure/layout/methods are up to scratch?

EDIT: Forget the URL, added that.
Normally I remember to omit the closing php tag...

In tandem with this I am building a PHP Blocks type thing, It's still early days for both projects.

```
<?php

    /****
    *
    *   ecCore Provides low-level debugging, error and exception functionality
    *   Matthew Day (CFHC Web Development 2011)
    *    @package: ExCx
    *   @version: 1.0
    *
    ****/

  class ecCore
  {

    //The following constants allow for pretty call backs to static methods
    const backtrace                                 = 'ecCore::backtrace';
    const call                                      = 'ecCore::call';
    const callback                                  = 'ecCore::callback';
    const checkOS                                   = 'ecCore::checkOS';
    const checkVersion                              = 'ecCore::checkVersion';
    const configureSMTP                             = 'ecCore::configureSMTP';
    const debug                                     = 'ecCore::debug';
    const detectOpcodeCache                         = 'ecCore::detectOpcodeCache';
    const disableContext                            = 'ecCore::disableContext';
    const dump                                      = 'ecCore::dump';
    const enableDebugging                           = 'ecCore::enableDebugging';
    const enableDynamicConstants                    = 'ecCore::enableDynamicConstants';
    const enableErrorHandling                       = 'ecCore::enableErrorHandling';
    const enableExceptionHandling                   = 'ecCore::enableExceptionHandling';
    const expose                                    = 'ecCore::expose';
    const getDebug                                  = 'ecCore::getDebug';
    const handleError                               = 'ecCore::handleError';
    const handleException                           = 'ecCore::handleException';
    const registerDebugCallback                     = 'ecCore::registerDebugCallback';
    const reset                                     = 'ecCore::reset';
    const sendMessagesOnShutdown                    = 'ecCore::sendMessagesOnShutdown';
    const startErrorCapture                         = 'ecCore::startErrorCapture';
    const stopErrorCapture                          = 'ecCore::stopErrorCapture';

    static private $captured_error_level = 0;
    static private $captured_error_regex = array();
    static private $captured_error_types = array();
    static private $captured_errors = array();
    static private $captured_errors_previous_handler = array();
    static private $context_shown = FALSE;
    static private $debug = NULL;
    static private $debug_callback = NULL;
    static private $dynamic_constants = FALSE;
    static private $error_destination = 'html';
    static private $error_message_queue = array();
    static private $exception_destination = 'html';
    static private $exception_handler_callback = NULL;
    static private $exception_handler_parameters = array();
    static private $exception_message = NULL;
    static private $handles_errors = FALSE;
    static private $handles_exceptions = FALSE;
    static private $show_context = TRUE
    static private $smtp_connection = NULL;
    static private $smtp_from_email = NULL;

    //Creates a nicely formatted backtrace to where the method is initally called
    static public function backtrace($remove_lines=0, $backtrace=NULL)
    {
      if ($remove_lines !== NULL && !is_numeric($remove_lines))
      {
        $remove_lines = 0;
      }

      settype($remove_lines, 'integer');

      $doc_root = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
      $doc_root .= (substr($doc_root, -1) != DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR) ? DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR : '';

      if ($backtrace === NULL)
      {
        $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
      }

      while ($remove_lines > 0)
      {
        array_shift($backtrace);
        $remove_lines--;
      }

      $backtrace = array_reverse($backtrace);

      $bt_string = '';
      $i = 0;
      foreach ($backtrace as $call)
      {
        if ($i)
        {
          $bt_string .= "\n";
        }
         if (isset($call['file']))
         {
            $bt_string .= str_replace($doc_root, '{doc_root}' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $call['file']) . '(' . $call['line'] . '): ';
         } else
         {
            $bt_string .= '[internal function]: ';
         }
         if (isset($call['class'])) 
         {
            $bt_string .= $call['class'] . $call['type'];
         }
        if (isset($call['class']) || isset($call['function'])) 
        {
          $bt_string .= $call['function'] . '(';
           $j = 0;
          if (!isset($call['args'])) 
          {
            $call['args'] = array();
          }
          foreach ($call['args'] as $arg)
          {
            if ($j)
            {
                $bt_string .= ', ';
            }
            if (is_bool($arg))
            {
                $bt_string .= ($arg) ? 'true' : 'false';
            } elseif (is_null($arg)) 
            {
                $bt_string .= 'NULL';
            } elseif (is_array($arg))
            {
               $bt_string .= 'Array';
            } elseif (is_object($arg))
            {
                $bt_string .= 'Object(' . get_class($arg) . ')';
            } elseif (is_string($arg)) 
            {
                // Shorten the UTF-8 string if it is too long
                if (strlen(utf8_decode($arg)) > 18)
                {
                    // If we can't match as unicode, try single byte
                    if (!preg_match('#^(.{0,15})#us', $arg, $short_arg))
                    {
                        preg_match('#^(.{0,15})#s', $arg, $short_arg);
                    }
                    $arg  = $short_arg[0] . '...';
                }
                $bt_string .= "'" . $arg . "'";
            } else 
            {
                $bt_string .= (string) $arg;
            }
        }
            $bt_string .= ')';
        }
        $i++;
       }       
      return $bt_string;
    }  // end of the backtrace function


    /****
    *
    * Performs a [http://php.net/call_user_func call_user_func()], while translating PHP 5.2 static callback syntax for PHP 5.1 and 5.0
    *
    ****/

    static public function call($callback, $parameters=array())
    {
        //Fix PHP 5.0 and 5.1 static callback syntax
        if (is_string($callback) && strpos($callback, '::') !== FALSE)
        {
            $callback = explode('::', $callback);
        }

        $parameters = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);
        if (sizeof($parameters) == 1 && is_array($parameters[0]))
        {
            $parameters = $parameters[0];
        }

        return call_user_func_array($callback, $parameters);
    }

    /****
    *
    * Translates a Class::method style static method callback to array style for compatibility with PHP 5.0 and 5.1 and built-in PHP functions
    *
    ****/

    /****
    *
    *   Checks an error/exception destination to make sure it is valid
    *
    ****/
    static private function checkDestination($destination)
        {
            if ($destination == 'html') {
                return 'html';
            }

            if (preg_match('~^(?:                                                                         # Allow leading whitespace
                               (?:[^\x00-\x20\(\)<>@,;:\\\\"\.\[\]]+|"[^"\\\\\n\r]+")                     # An "atom" or a quoted string
                               (?:\.[ \t]*(?:[^\x00-\x20\(\)<>@,;:\\\\"\.\[\]]+|"[^"\\\\\n\r]+"[ \t]*))*  # A . plus another "atom" or a quoted string, any number of times
                              )@(?:                                                                       # The @ symbol
                               (?:[a-z0-9\\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}|                                              # Domain name
                               (?:(?:[01]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[01]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])    # (or) IP addresses
                              )
                              (?:\s*,\s*                                                                  # Any number of other emails separated by a comma with surrounding spaces
                               (?:
                                (?:[^\x00-\x20\(\)<>@,;:\\\\"\.\[\]]+|"[^"\\\\\n\r]+")
                                (?:\.[ \t]*(?:[^\x00-\x20\(\)<>@,;:\\\\"\.\[\]]+|"[^"\\\\\n\r]+"[ \t]*))*
                               )@(?:
                                (?:[a-z0-9\\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}|
                                (?:(?:[01]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[01]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])
                               )
                              )*$~xiD', $destination)) {
                return 'email';
            }

            $path_info     = pathinfo($destination);
            $dir_exists    = file_exists($path_info['dirname']);
            $dir_writable  = ($dir_exists) ? is_writable($path_info['dirname']) : FALSE;
            $file_exists   = file_exists($destination);
            $file_writable = ($file_exists) ? is_writable($destination) : FALSE;

            if (!$dir_exists || ($dir_exists && ((!$file_exists && !$dir_writable) || ($file_exists && !$file_writable)))) {
                return FALSE;
            }

            return 'file';
        }





  } // End of class


?>
```

Comment: Erm, 404 Not Found.

Comment: Please post code, not just links to code. See the FAQ for more information.

Answer (score 12):

I haven't read the source code entirely, but here a few things that came to mind immediately:

- Use PHP Docblocks, so my IDE can support me when using your code
- Please break down `backtrace()` into smaller functions which are understandable in an instant or insert some inline comments above those crazy if/else/string operations in this function.
- Omit the closing `?>` when you have a PHP only file, because it might give you alot of headaches (weird spaces popping up in your HTML output which you won't find easily)
- Make `__construct` and `__clone` (even if they don't contain any code) private if you have a static class. This way somebody who uses your class and doesn't bother to look into the source or docs will realize how to use your class faster.
- Don't use String concatenation (`.=`) in a loop. Build some kind of data structure like an array within this loop and `implode()` afterwards. Much easier to understand and faster since concatenating strings is very expensive.
- If you want other people to use and maintain your code, please provide at least better description what this code does, some sample usage and output.

Comment: +1 agree with most statements, except string concatenation vs. implode perf, see http://www.sitepoint.com/high-performance-string-concatenation-in-php/. however this is micro-optimization. About readability, it depends on what you will do after the loop (+ may be quite subjective): check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847356/string-concatenation-vs-array-implode-in-php